# Ajax and returning data limit (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, file

1. I'm using jquery to do an ajax call on 3 types of files html/javascript and img file:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "text",
       async: true,
       success: function(data) {
           data = data.replace('<', '&lt;');
           data = data.replace('>', '&gt;');
           $('#file_content').html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');    
       },
       error: function(a,b,c){
           alert("There has been an error! Try again...");
       } 
   });
   ```

   - The html file is this:

     ```
     <link href = "{get_url}style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" />
     <script language = "javascript">
         var get_url = '{get_url}';
     </script>   
     <script src = "{get_url}functions.js" language = "javascript"></script>

     <div id="screen">
         <div id="floor"></div>
         <div id="ceiling"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="minimapcontainer">
         <canvas id="minimap"></canvas>
         <canvas id="minimapobjects"></canvas>
     </div>
     ```

   The data returned is this:

   ```
   <link href = "{get_url}style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" />
   ```

   The rest seems to get run as html even though i'm doing a replace for the less than and greater than signs... Really I need it to return the content unprocessed as html. how do I do this? **-SOLVED, Thanks**
2. Now moving onto the other questions about retrieving an image from an image url and why the javascript file returns a snipped off version of the data:

   - The js file is 8956 characters long and it seems to snip it off at 8343... Why might it be doing this?
   - The image files (opening a direct url to the image) get returned as the binary data (I guess) rather than the image... The character length of the returning result is 18615. How do i return the image rather than the data the makes up the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tsrfq/

However, it is only replacing the first occurrence of "<" and ">", try using a global regexp instead.

```
data = data.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
data = data.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsrfq/1/

Comment: Well the regex works great for that bit... Thanks a bunch!

Can you take a look at the remaining questions :)

Comment: What other questions? When the html gets "snipped" what is missing? What images are you referring to?

Comment: I'll create a new question.. I imagine the above seems confusing.